# hot deploy scss in Vaadin (Netbeans)

Tags: netbeans, vaadin

Sorry for my newbish question.
I'm working with Vaadin using netbeans ide 8, and i'm tuning my client-side aspect of my application, by adding in mytheme.scss the style corrections. I don't want to rebuild all the theme, but only some adjustments, as image scaling and so no.
Now, i see that that modifications are not applied "on the fly" on my web application. I need to stop and restart jetty embedded server. Also, if i use external web service (as tomcat), stopping and restarting is not enough: i need to clean and build again to see the effect of the graphical tuning.

Can i activate in some way hot deploy of my scss?

Answer (score 1):

When using the netbeans vaadin adon, you will receive a "Compile Theme" entry in your project.
This compiles your SCSS files and it should then redepoly just the css files.

Of course you will have to press F5 to refresh the browser...

[image]

Comment: is there a way to do this automatically when .scss file is changed and saved?